# How can I get database's content data?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I get database's content data? I wrote in index.py,

```
def index():
    user_data = UserData.query.filter_by(id=1)
    return render_template('index.html', user_data=user_data)
```

in index.html

```
   <div>
        <p>{{ user_data.name }}</p>
   </div>
```

in models.py

```
class UserData(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
```

When I show index.html in browser,jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'name' is undefined error happens.I rewrote in index.py,

```
def index():
    user_data = UserData.query.filter_by(id=1).all()
    return render_template('index.html', user_data=user_data)
```

but same error happens.How can i get& show name value whose id=1 in index.html?How should I fix this code?

Comment: Maybe `UserData.query.filter_by(id=1).one()` or `UserData.query.filter_by(id=1).first()`? (comment not answer because I'm guessing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your query returns a list of objects, not a single object.

Eric Wilson's comment is correct. `.all()` will return a list while `.one()` (I prefer `.first()`) will return a single object with `.name` as a property.